# What is this "famous" love song played in many American romantic/highschool ball movies?

Tags: identify-this-song

This has been bugging me for a very long time now. There is this song which I know I've heard in "countless" American movies from the 1990s and maybe 1980s, usually when there is a ball or prom and the romantic music starts playing so they can slow-dance. Basically, it starts with a soft tune going:

> Duuuuuuuu-du-du-duuuuuu-duuu... something, something... (uhu)...

The "something, something" part are words spoken by a soft male voice. I think. I'm unsure if the "duuu" part is also accompanied by a human voice, or if it's some instrument. It's very calm/relaxed/romantic.

I can't remember the rest of the song at all, but I will know it when I hear it. The beginning is what has really stuck with me.

My guess is that the song is made somewhere between 1980 and 1995, but I could be wrong. It's supposedly very famous/known/played/popular, but I've now listened through countless "1990s love song" playlists and the likes and not heard it in nay of those.

Not finding this song is driving me nuts. Please help!

Comment: In which movies did you hear it?

Comment: Could you provide rough music notation, or perhaps someone you know might be able to provide it? That would help. What you've provided is a bit too ambiguous.

Comment: For the benefit of new visitors to this question, the OP has confirmed that [@RichJackson's answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/10108/3955) identifies the song they were after.

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess, but how about ["Unchained Melody"](https://youtu.be/qiiyq2xrSI0) by the Righteous Brothers?

It's actually from 1965, but it's considered an iconic love song, and has appeared in countless movies.

Comment: This would actually be my guess as well! :)

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [True](https://youtu.be/AR8D2yqgQ1U) by Spandau Ballet.

- Song has been used in *many* [films and TV shows](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1277538/) since its release in 1983
- Includes soft male voice in chorus
- The structure that was described seems to match the cadence of the melody in the song's chorus (although, it's Hu's instead of Du's :-))